# Managing messages in chat room with MongoDB and Graphql

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, performance, graphql

I am wondering how to manage messages in my chat room. My assumptions are:

1. There is a collection `rooms` with fields like `id`, `messages`, `participants`
2. There can be many rooms with many participants

Now, I have doubts:

1. should I have separate collection with `messages` (`id`, `author`, `text`, where `author` is a reference to `users` collection)?
2. Or maybe should I keep simple objects in `messages` instead of documents with refs?

I can imagine that collection with messages will be huuuuge (if is not cleared). Will Mongo handle it? Or maybe there is a better way for doing that?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the scale of what you're building.

I would say that, what meatsacks like you and me consider to be huge amounts is often peanuts for database systems (be it relational or a nosql datastore).

It's hard to say without knowing anything about the project, but i suspect you'll likely be better off, if you design your data model based on correctness/usefulness, and worry about performance as a next step.

Based on the entities you describe (rooms, messages, participants, users, ...) i'm picturing an application such as Discord. In such a case i would think of rooms and users as first order entities and both participants and messages as (big) ordered lists of data belonging to a room (while each entry in both obviously also has a reference to its personal user/author).

Comment: That's how it works but in MongoDB you have functionality called populate. I can have something like `messages: [ObjectID('...') ...]` or `messages: [{}, {}...]`. The first approach requires additional collection for `messages`